# Best expiration setting for cookies in this situation?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm creating a relationship table of user sessions (each user regardless of login state gets a new user session unless they already have a cookie denoting the session ID of their current session) and webpages on my site. This will eventually be able to predict interests, in theory.

Now, I've decided that I should use a PHP cookie rather than a PHP session. How long should I set the cookie to be around for? (I currently have it at 24 hours)

Are there any negatives to setting cookies to have a long period of time before expiration? What about non-expiring cookies? How does a major website set cookie expiration times for things like "Most recently viewed items"?

Comment: Cookies are not used (i believe) for somehting like most recently viewed, cookies are on the client side, not on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expire them at all (or only in a year or so) if you intend to use the cookies to track users for a long time - as  the user visits the page and you find out the cookie data is obsolete, you can delete them using `setcookie()` (set expiration date to somewhere in the past).

Note that many users have cookies disabled, or have them automatically deleted when they close their browser, for *exactly* this reason. People don't like to get tracked.

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing to protect from session hijacking? How do you handle people who may visit from a shared computer, do they get the same session?

I would suggest setting up a user login and track information by user. Otherwise, the data you get will not be qualified and can only be guessing at best.

Comment: I may just do that. I have a login system in place, so maybe I'll only track the trends of logged-in users.